# image without initial src doesn't display css background-image: url("image.png");

Tags: html, css

I have a table with the same small image on every row.

Seen as the table has thousands of rows, **I'd like to not set the src**, width and height of the image **in html** and instead do this with css using a class.

```
.clbtn {
width: 18px; 
height: 18px;
background-image: url("image.png");
}
```

Doing this would decrease the initial size of the page.

However while this work fine in chrome it doesn't in firefox.
Is there another way around this than a `$(document).ready(function(){ $(".clbtn").attr("src", "image.png");});` after the table?

Comment: why using `img`, use a div with background-image.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but somehow the onclick event is messed up and the new image after a click is missing some pixels at the bottom.
`$(this).css("background-image", "url(/images/image.png)");` is the on click event. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: sorry i did not get you, you never mentioned `onclick` event for the image or its functionality. can you update the question?

Comment: It's ok I'll just stick to the jQuery workaround to not complicate things. Thanks for the suggestion tho =) I'll keep this question here just in case someone stumbles upon the same problem within the next 5 years and doesn't think of jquery'ing a class =p

Answer (score 0):

That's because how the browser handle images with missing src attrs. Perhaps the most sensate thing to do if you really need to do this this way, is to src all the img with a 1x1 transparent gif.

Comment: Not really that would kinda be the same, 2500 times src="a.gif" adds 31.6 kB to the html page size :p

Comment: I'm happy with my jQuery, it's not very elegant but so far it's the most effective way ;)